# Is it possible to optimize this solution any further?

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

I want to find minimum integral solution for y in constant (O(1)) or O(log(n)) time complexity. The equation is `x*n+1=y*m` , here n and m are known constants. (where 1<=x<=n)

Currently the best solution I have thought of is to linearly iterate on all possible values of x from 1 to n and as soon as for any x , `(x*n+1)` is divisible by m then break the loop and report ans as `(x*n+1)/m`

```
for x in range(1,n+1):
     if((x*n+1)%m==0):
        print((x*n+1)/m)
        break
```

I just want to know whether I can eliminate this `for` loop and have a constant or logarithmic time solution. Thanks You !!!

Comment: The minimum solution can be found from the continued fraction of m/n, which you can compute in O(log(max(m,n)).

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to do this ?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to search for a link that already has the explanation. Better than typing it once again.

Comment: Look [here](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf) on page 36. If you haven't read about continued fractions before, you can read the previous chapter.

Comment: Equivalently, you can do the [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). It computes the GCD of m and n (which should be 1 for your problem to have solutions), but it also gives you a solution.